# can't switch to another value in DropDownList (it switches back to former value) in ASP C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

My aspx file where the DDL is defined:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="myDDL" runat="server"
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="myDdlChange" 
     AutoPostBack="true"  EnableViewState="true" />
```

My code behind file

```
protected void PopulateControl()
{
    //populate my DDL based on an array (OK)
}

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    PopulateControl();
}

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
            base.OnLoad(e);
            ...
            this.DataBind();
}
protected void myDdlChange(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["myDDL"] = myDDL.SelectedValue;
    myTextBox.Text = MyMethod(myDDL.SelectedValue);
}
```

`myTextBox` is a text box which is populated every time the DDL changes based through a method that takes the selected value as parameter.

What more needs to be added for the DDL to keep the user's selected value.
Right now, when I switch to another value in the DDL, my selected value is switched back to the first element of the array.

Also, why doesn't `myDdlChange` method take focus when I debug and switch to another value in the DDL? (I've a breakpoint inside this method)

Answer (score 3):

Because every time you do this:

```
PopulateControl();
```

You remove all of the values in the DropDownList and re-add them.  So whatever the user selected was removed, and a fresh list of (unselected) values was added.  This happens every time the page loads, which takes place before the `myDdlChange` handler.

You can prevent this from re-populating the list on post-backs:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    PopulateControl();
```

That way the DropDownList is populated only on an initial page load and not on subsequent post-back page loads.

> Also, why doesn't myDdlChange method take focus when I debug and switch to another value in the DDL?

Are you posting back to the server when you switch to another value?  If not then nothing is invoking server-side code.  If you are posting back to the server, have you registered this event with the control?  The designer normally does this for you, but if you created this manually then you'd need to register it with the control manually as well.

Comment: Thank you David. Problem has been if i do that (PopulateControl only if not postback)the ddl is emptied when i switch to another value in the ddl. About the second question: I was expecting the myDdlChange method to be invoked because of the way the control is defined: `OnSelectedIndexChanged="myDdlChange"`.

Comment: @rogermorre: What else is emptying the `DropDownList` then?  Or maybe you've disabled its state?  (I forget the exact term, it's been a long time since I've had to use web forms.  But controls store their state at the page level unless told otherwise.)  As for the invoking of the change method, that is how you'd wire up the event.  But if you're not invoking a post back when you change the value then there's nothing invoking that event.  Or maybe by clobbering and re-populating the control you are also removing the event handler?  You're not showing that code, so I can't know.